# Why would the first write to Mio's TcpStream after accepting give an "operation would block" error?

Tags: rust, mio

With this code:

```
poll.poll(&mut poll_events, Some(Duration::from_secs(0)));
for event in poll_events.iter() {
    match event.token() {
        LISTENER_TOKEN => {
            let (mut stream, addr) = unwrap_or_continue!(
                listener.accept(),
                "Failed to accept incoming connection"
            );
            unwrap_or_continue!(
                stream.write("Hello, world!\n".as_bytes()),
                &format!("Failed to write to {}", addr)
            );
        }
        _ => unreachable!()
    }
}
```

where `unwrap_or_continue!` just does `continue` on an error while reporting it, I get this error:

```
Failed to write to 127.0.0.1:49231: operation would block
```

Why would it block, the socket just got accepted and it's a first write?

Comment: Practically, why does it matter? You need to write your code to handle blocking, otherwise there's no real reason to use MIO.

Comment: True, I thought `write()` on a nonblocking socket cannot block, but after revisiting `write(2)` docs, it's a valid scenario.

Comment: *a nonblocking socket cannot block* — Isn't that why it returns an error telling you it would have blocked... instead of blocking?

Comment: @Shepmaster Like I said, revisiting Linux `write(2)` I see that `EWOULDBLOCK` is a valid error. Didn't think that possible before, since it doesn't seem there's anything to block on, as `write(2)` can already return 0 bytes written in case the buffer is full or something. So I was thinking I was doing something wrong with Mio.

Comment: There's two different points in play here. Your main question is "why does it block in this case", which is a valid enough question. In the comments you seem to be surprised at the *mechanism* of how non-blocking works. Non-blocking sockets work by returning an error whenever the write would have blocked.

Comment: This type of error happens when there are no more free space for writing into the OS network stack buffer reserved to the connection. No idea why you hit this problem, you should not have such error in your scenario.